# partial Differential equation solution with Cos term inside

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

consider this equation:

$$\frac  {∂^2 T}{∂r^2 }+ \frac 1r \frac {∂T}{∂r}+ \frac 1{r^2} \frac {∂^2 T}{∂θ^2}+k v (\cos(θ) \frac{∂T}{∂r} -\frac 1r\sin(θ))-k \frac{∂T}{∂t}=0$$

within this boundary condition:

$$T(r,\theta,0)=0$$
$$\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial r} = - \dfrac{q}{2 \pi r \lambda }$$

I think about separational variable and green's function to solve the above equation , but I have a problem 4th term (last term) of the left hand side of my equation.

Could you please help me how can I dealing with this problem? (Any suggestions)

Thanks,
Sanaz

Comment: Use latex /Mathjax syntax for your equations. I will edit the second line the rest is up to you. Click on edit to see how to use LaTeX syntax on MathStackExchange (MSE).

Comment: This problem seems intractable.

Comment: $T(r,\theta)=\theta$ and 
$\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial r} = - \dfrac{q}{2 \pi \lambda \cos \theta}$
 are not a well defined boundary conditions. So, the question is non-sens.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. the boundary is not importan for me, just the solution of the governing equation is my problem. I have changed it.

Comment: The boundary conditions are is still inconsistent. $T(r,\theta,t)=0 \quad\to\quad \frac{\partial T}{\partial r}=0$ which is contradictory to the second condition ( Probably due to the lack of definition of boundaries). I doubt that a solution of the PDE could be found without consistent boundary conditions.

Comment: The first one is the initial condition. which is equal to zero. but I don't want the whole solution. i want to know how to dealing with governing equation for example how to use separation of variable to solve this kind of equation.

Comment: Your equation is now inhomogeneous and there is no hope to apply separation of variables, if ever had been one.

Comment: I don't think the equation is inhomogeneous.

Comment: @sanaz : Your PDE has been modified. Now:  $$\frac  {∂^2 T}{∂r^2 }+ \frac 1r \frac {∂T}{∂r}+ \frac 1{r^2} \frac {∂^2 T}{∂θ^2}+k v (\cos(θ) \frac{∂T}{∂r} -\frac 1r\sin(θ))-k \frac{∂T}{∂t}=0$$. Is it the last change? Into it there is  an undefined symbol $v$. Is it a constant or a function? unknown or given ? The method of separation of variables cannot be used. There is few hope for analytical solving. A very little hope with the method of characteristics which cannot be use without well specified boundary conditions. This is not the case with the second condition on an undefined boundary).

Comment: Yes, I add it may be it helps. It is velocity.

Comment: $v$ is a constant or a function? unknown or given?

Comment: v is the constant speed.

Comment: You have now a term, $-kv\sin(\theta)/r$ that does not depends on $T$. Then, your equation is inhomogeneous.